# Perl: read an array and calculate corresponding percentile

Tags: perl

I am trying to code for a perl code that reads a text file with a series of number, calculates, and prints out the numbers that corresponds to the percentiles. I do not have access to the other statistical modules, so I'd like to stick with just pure perl coding. Thanks in advance!

The input text file looks like:

```
197
98
251
82
51
272
154
167
38
280
157
212
188
88
40
229
228
125
292
235
67
70
127
26
279
.... (and so on)
```

The code I have is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data;

open (my $fh, "<", "testing2.txt")
                         or die "Cannot open: $!\n";
while (<$fh>){
    push @data, $_;
}
close $fh;

my %count;
foreach my $datum (@data) {
    ++$count{$datum};
}

my %percentile;
my $total = 0;
foreach my $datum (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %count) {
    $total += $count{$datum};
    $percentile{$datum} = $total / @data;
    # percentile subject to change
    if ($percentile{$datum} <= 0.10) {   
        print "$datum : $percentile{$datum}\n\n";
    }
}
```

My desired output:

```
2 : 0.01
3 : 0.01333
4 : 0.01666
6 : 0.02
8 : 0.03
10 : 0.037
12 : 0.04
14 : 0.05
15 : 0.05333
16 : 0.06
18 : 0.06333
21 : 0.07333
22 : 0.08
25 : 0.09
26 : 0.09666
```

Where the format is #number from the list : #corresponding percentile

Comment: How is the output of your script different from the desirable one?

Comment: For some odd reason, nothing pops up on the left side (#number from the list), and it only shows the #corresponding percentile

Comment: Note off-topic: You can replace the `while`-loop with `my @data = <$fh>`

Comment: @zdim I've added the chomp, but the #number from the list doesn't print out together with the #corresponding percentile

Comment: @zdim Printing and the data doesn't seem to be an issue. The only weird thing is that the #number from the list isn't printing out, while others said that it printed out in their side.

Comment: @Sunny  I deleted my previous comments since you responded, to reduce the noise. Your code and data (copied from here) work for me, it prints fine. (I did add `chomp @data;`, but that is not this problem.)

Comment: @zdim, according to choroba, he told me that it may be caused due to an incompatible input file; which right now, I'm trying to learn how to convert it into *nix style.

Comment: Agree, that is the best guess -- and I agree that it is best do it in the code, just like [choroba](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba) says. Perhaps first try with a small file with numbers that you type up in a normal editor, to confirm that it is about data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store the numer wihtout a newline in @data, just add `chomp;` before pushing it, or `chomp @data;` after you've read them all.

If your input file has MSWin style newlines, convert it to *nix style using `dos2unix` or `fromdos`.

Also, try to learn how to indent your code, it boosts readability. And consider renaming `$total` to `$running_total`, as you use the value as it changes.

Comment: I've added the chomp, but the #number from the list still doesn't print out together with the #corresponding percentile.

Comment: I'll take a look at the input file. Thanks.

Comment: My original input file was originated from an excel file (saved as  tab-delimited file), would that possibly be the issue? And I can't seem to convert my file using the linux command.

Comment: @Sunny: So try to remove the line ends in the code:  `s/\xd//g` before pushing. Also, what do you mean by "I can't seem to convert"?

Comment: As in command not found, seems like the conversion requires me to download a module or add-on.

Comment: I removed the end line before pushing, but I am still not getting the number printed.

Comment: Problem solved!  It's indeed due to the input file format! Thanks a lot for the help! (It worked after I converted input file into *nix style)